# ObjectMapper writeValueAsString() method convert field name into lowercase

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have entity named as Data

```
class Data
{
    String Name;
    int Age;
    // Constructor & Getters & Setters
}
```

When I use `ObjectMapper`

```
Data objData = new Data("XYZ",3);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(objData));
```

Output :

```
{"name":"XYZ","age":3}
```

it convert field name into lower case.

How can I get output like

```
{"Name":"XYZ","Age":3}
```

Comment: Why don't you just follow naming convention in the first place, by naming the fields in lower case?

Comment: I need in Uppercase to pass json to some RESTAPI.

Comment: Respect the Java naming conventions in Java code, even if the JSON fields do not respect it. See http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use [@JsonProperty](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html)?
Here's how.

```
@JsonProperty("Name")
public String getName(){
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("Age")
public int getAge() {
  return age;
}
```